# Remove unwanted info from a series in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I extract the text in my images column from `/images/` until `.png`

I have a pandas dataframe containing the following information

```
>>> animals
```

[image]

The column I want to manipulate is the `image` column

```
0     {'url': '/images/bengal-tiger_image.png', 'lic...
1     {'url': '/images/giant-panda_image.png', 'lice...
2     {'url': '/images/blue-whale_image.png', 'licen...
3     {'url': '/images/asian-elephant_image.png', 'l...
4     {'url': '/images/gorilla_image.png', 'licence'...
5     {'url': '/images/snow-leopard_image.png', 'lic...
6     {'url': '/images/orangutan_image.png', 'licenc...
7     {'url': '/images/sea-turtle_image.png', 'licen...
8     {'url': '/images/black-rhino_image.png', 'lice...
9     {'url': '/images/african-penguin_image.png', '...
10    {'url': '/images/red-panda_image.png', 'licenc...
11    {'url': '/images/polar-bear_image.png', 'licen...
Name: image, dtype: object
```

My current attempt is the following:

```
animals['image'] = animals.apply(lambda x: x['image'](len["/images/":]))
```

But this produces the following error:

```
KeyError: 'image'
```

Any suggestions welcome thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
left_string = '/images/'
right_string = '.png'

animals['image_text'] = animals['image'].apply(lambda x: x['url'][len(left_string):len(x['url'])-len(right_string)])
```

Remember x is a dictionary so you need to use 'url' as the key.

Comment: I finally understand what the 'url' part is for thank you so much!

Comment: I see what you did there, its the first piece of code I've tried thats worked. I've gotten the text just fine but perhaps I wasnt clear, I am trying to extract both the /image/ and .png part as it is part of a link I am trying to use

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, thanks to your help I understand what I needed to do and I have fixed it. Thank you so much!
Below is the code I needed
animals['image_text_2'] = animals['image'].apply(lambda x: x['url'])

Comment: Gotcha!  At least now you know how to trim off the beginning or end if you ever need to.